# how to convert a binary string into polynomial form

Tags: c, file-handling

I have a binary string in the form of 1001 and i want  to convert it into x^3+1 in c.How it is possible ?
Is there is any built-in function for that.

Comment: *What* error?  Be specific.

Comment: Why can't you just have a fgets() to read the file and have a pointer to your fgets() and just increment that pointer to point to the 3rd char and write from there to your file?

Comment: `fscanf(f, "%d", ...);` --> `fscanf(f, "%1d", ...);` to read only 1 digit.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a binary string in the form of 1001 and i want to convert it
>   into x^3+1 in c.How it is possible ? Is there is any built-in function
>   for that.

There is no built-in function for that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char binary_string[] = "1001";
    int degree = strlen(binary_string) - 1, exponent, terms = 0;
    for (exponent = degree; 0 <= exponent; --exponent)
        if (binary_string[degree-exponent] == '1')
        {
            if (terms++) printf("+");
            switch (exponent)
            {
            case 0:     printf("1");                break;
            case 1:     printf("x");                break;
            default:    printf("x^%d", exponent);   break;
            }
        }
    puts("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing with all that xor bidness... The basic unit is a byte, so I you want to write a file that is basically shifted two bits to the left you will have to composite each byte...

```
outByte1 = inByte1 << 2 | (inByte2 & 0xc0) >> 6
```